# Meteor website delay to identify {{currentuser}}

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I am new to Meteor. What I want is when I go to the page if the user is logged in, show **"Logged In"** and if not show **"Not Logged In"**, here the is snippet I tried that,

```
{{#if currentUser}} Logged In {{else}} Not Logged In {{/if}}
```

So when a "signed up" user comes I expect, directly showing "**Logged In**". But what happen is it shows **"Not Logged In"** first and then after about a second shows **"Logged In"**. How to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the user is still logging in. I recommend you define a helper as such:

```
Template.myTemplateName.helpers({
  authenticated: function() {
    return Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn();
  }
})
```

and then use it like you want:

```
{{#if authenticated}} Logged In {{else}} Not Logged In {{/if}}
```